# Collection of short stories by different authors

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I am trying to track down a volume of short stories by different authors.  I am certain that one was "The Small Assassin" by Ray Bradbury, probably the first story in the volume.  I am pretty certain that it also contained "Inconstant Moon" by Larry Niven, and the Eric Frank Russell short story "And Then There were None" (I hope that is the right title for the short story.  All I can remember is that a spaceship lands on a planet, and all the inhabitants refuse to be intimidated by the Ambassador and his troops, using the phrase MYOB.)

I also have a vague recollection of one where a man is trying to help two children escape from robots, only to discover he is one himself, so he commits suicide. (Did he throw himself out of the window of a tall building?)  Another one is about inhabitants in a quiet town suddenly finding themselves on the receiving end of tourist trips from the future, much to their annoyance, as they no longer seem to have any privacy in their own homes.  They start to behave in such an obnoxious way that the tourists stop coming.

It was definitely published before 1985, but that is as close as I can get.  And if anyone could tell me who the authors of the last two are, and what the stories are called.

Comment: Could the time travel story be "Pawley's Peepholes" by John Wyndham?

Comment: [And Then There were None](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56117) / [Inconstant Moon](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41283) / [The Small Assassin](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58434) / [Pawley's Peepholes](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59861)

Comment: Times like these, I wish ISFDB had a feature where you could ask for works that shared a particular set of stories.

Comment: Pawley's Peepholes - that definitely rings a bell!  Definitely that one, thanks so much.  It has been driving me nuts!  Now all I need to know is what book they were all in.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - You could dump the results into Excel and ask it to de-duplicate the cells

Comment: I keep doing searches that will give me anthologies with the some of those authors, but with different stories.  The Small Assassin search only gives me Ray Bradbury short stories.

Comment: Do you remember if it was a BIG anthology or a small one, which could fit in a thinnish mass-market paperback?

Comment: As far as I can remember it wasn't a big anthology. It was definitely a paperback. I have looked at best of all time ones, again, they contain many of those authors, but not the stories I describe. I am positive about The Small Assassin, and now Pawley's Peepholes as well.

Comment: "The Small Assassin" was first published in 
 1946, and "Inconstant Moon" in 1971, in different magazines. This could be one of those "best of all time" anthologies, or even a historical one like James Gunn's _Alternate Worlds: The Illustrated History of Science Fiction_.

Comment: The Gunn anthology doesn't have its actual fiction contents listed in ISFDB.

Comment: I haven't found any anthology that has *any* of those stories in common! That in itself is kinda noteworthy :(

Comment: Oh dear. It is, of course, possible I am muddling up two different anthologies, both read a long time ago.  The book belonged to my brother, who remembers it as well, although not what it contained.  He does, however, think it was a Faber publication.  

If I do find out what it was, I will let you all know.

Comment: MYOB (Mind Your Own Business) is from "And Then There Were None", by Eric Frank Russel. The story is about a military ship landing on a that is planet ruled by benign anarchy.